# Corda Database Manager Failed to create datasource

Tags: corda

Upgrading a Corda node from CE3.2 to CE4.0 and following these documentation steps:

Running `ubuntu@ip-xyz:~$ java -jar tools-database-manager-4.0.jar dry-run -b /opt/corda/`

Gives error:

```
Exporting the current database migrations ...
Failed to create datasource.
Please check that the correct JDBC driver is installed in one of the following folders:
     - /opt/corda/drivers
     - plugins
     - cordapps
Caused By java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: plugins
2019-05-23 22:24:16,284 Thread-0 WARN Unable to register Log4j shutdown hook because JVM is shutting down. Using SimpleLogger
```

I have all the required folders in place for drivers, plugins and cordapps and have installed MS SQL drivers mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar.

Answer (score 0):

The `"jarDirs"` key in the node.conf was hiding the folders required for database migration.

By removing the following lines the database manager tool successfully completed the dry run.

```
    "jarDirs" : [
        "plugins",
        "cordapps"
    ]
```